# IE7 and setAttribute() to remove classes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, removeclass, setattribute

I've got a pretty interesting issue.
I'm writing a plugin which allows you to zoom in/out an image. I've got 3 buttons: close (close the 'window'), zoom in, zoom out.
The buttons zoom in/out have got disabled versions, too. Its activated when you reach the minimum/maximum amount of zoom.

If you open the picture to zoom, you can see an active zoom out button, and a disabled zoom in button (because I set the maximum value at opening). When you first clicked on the zoom out button, the zoom in button should get rid of disabled class.
It works fine in Safara, Chrome, Firefox 3.6/4/5, IE8 but not in IE7.

The zoom in button has an ID and classes and I want to force IE7 to remove specific classes from the element. First, I used removeClass(), but it didn't work. Then I use setAttribute(), which works in every browser but IE7.

Here is the example.
So, when you open the image to zoom, the zoom out button has ID="zoom-button-in" and 5 classes: zoom-icon, zoom-icon-small, zoom-button-in, zoom-button-disabled, zoom-button-disabled-in.
And I want to remove the 2 'disabled' classes. So I use this:

```
var elementZoomButtonIn = document.getElementById("zoom-button-in");
elementZoomButtonIn.setAttribute("class", "zoom-icon zoom-icon-small zoom-button-in");
```

I've tried to set the class empty before inserted the non-disabled classes, but didn't work.

Is this method working in IE7? (-:

Thank you, Guys!

Comment: Some useful info here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` are generally broken in IE 7 and earlier (and compatibility modes in later versions). Use the element's `className` property instead:

```
elementZoomButtonIn.className = "zoom-icon zoom-icon-small zoom-button-in";
```

Even if `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` weren't broken in IE, it's still generally easier and more reliable to use equivalent DOM properties instead.

Comment: Oh, I see (I hate those guys, by the way :D)

Before the setAttribute() I've got a getAttribute() method - that's why it didn't work. But I used jQuery's attr() and now everything is OK!

Tim, I really thank you! You just saved my life! :-)

Have a nice day!