# IE7 ignoring my .js css rules - CSS/Javascript issue?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7

I am using the classes .js and .no-js on the <html> element to differentiate between layouts that have Javascript and those that don't.

With the <html> element, I added a default class of 'no-js'. Then I include a single line of script in the header, `document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute("class","js");` to switch the html class to 'js'. Obviously this line of code will only work for browsers that have js enabled, so the <html> element will become <html class="js"> whereas non-js enabled browsers will continue to read <html class="no-js">.

And then I will simply use `.js someElement{ font-weight:bold;}` versus `.no-js someElement{ font-weight:normal;}` to style my page differently.

However, I find that this approach fails dramatically on IE7. On IE7, the script works - or so it seems. On Developer Tools, it shows <html class="js">. However, ALL css styling that start with .js are ignored by IE7, and IE7 behaves as though the <html> element has a class of .no-js. (Check out http://bit.ly/LMre3N to get a clearer picture.)

I can't begin to imagine what exactly is wrong here: is this a case of IE7 behaving wrongly when rendering CSS, or is it a case of scripting not working properly? Here's what I tried:

**CSS**

1. Changing the order of .js and .no-js declarations, as I figured it could be the latter overriding the former that's causing the problem - NOPE.
2. Changing the order of the script and stylesheets, since it might be because IE7 read the .no-js stylesheet before it read the script - NOPE.
3. Changing the specificity of the declarations - perhaps being more specific will lead IE7 to read the .js declarations - NOPE.
4. Removing the .no-js class from the document altogether, hoping that IE7 will thus read .js declarations. NOPE - it simply ignores both the .no-js and the .js declarations.

In short, IE7 totally and completely ignore the fact that there is a .js declaration. So I figured it might be the script that had problems, and here's what I did:

**Javascript**

1. I added 'type="text-javascript"' to <script> - No effect.
2. I tried `document.documentElement` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]` - still the same.
3. I used `var htmlOrWhat=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
   alert(htmlOrWhat);`, FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE8, and IE9 returns '[object HTMLHtmlElement]', whereas IE7 returns [object], leading me to think IE7 is not reading the <html> element properly.
4. I then tried to read the id and lang attributes of <html> to test if IE7 is actually reading the element properly and yes, it retrieves these attributes correctly, it just simply refuse to apply .js css declarations to it.

By now, I'm at my wits' end (though I suspect the [object] anomaly is related to my problem), and I hope someone here at Stackoverflow will be able to help me out. I will really appreciate it if someone can point out *exactly* what's wrong with IE7 here, and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your block is lime in all browsers I have at hand btw (JS is enabled).

Comment: This is probably not the answer but it's `"text/javascript"` and not `"text-javascript"` inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Your doctype is also wrong - it should be <!DOCTYPE HTML>, although this isn't causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks poepje and John, those are silly typing mistakes that, as you mentioned, don't contribute to the problem.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` are generally broken in IE7 and earlier (and compatibility modes in later versions). Use the element's className property instead.

`document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className = "js";`

Here's a fiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ajcw/6Yz8x/1/

Comment: Thanks man! Didn't occur to me that it might be setAttribute()...since it actually did add the .js class to the html element according to my Developer Tools. By the way, do you have any idea why IE7 returned [object] with document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];?

Comment: Sorry YAWD, I'm not sure why IE7 returned this.

Answer (score 2):

SetAttribute() doesn't work as you might expect in IE7. It won't set an attribute on an item after it has been created. You'll need another way to handle the change in IE7.

The answer below suggests using the className property. Or you could probably just use jQuery.

(More: [IE7 and setAttribute() to remove classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465269/ie7-and-setattribute-to-remove-classes))

Comment: Thanks for explaining _exactly_ what's wrong with setAttribute() - that helps me to understand why to choose className over it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

setAttribute() and getAttribute() are broken in IE 7

check this out:
[IE7 and setAttribute() to remove classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465269/ie7-and-setattribute-to-remove-classes)